# Изменить элементы графиков в R

Tags: r

Помогите, пожалуйста...

Пусть df – мой фрейм данных (содержащий, в
частности, числовые переменные x, y, z). Итак,

```
    sub <- subset (df, select=c(x,y,z))  
    pairs(sub)
```

Построились 9 картинок (3 на 3) попарных
регрессии! А теперь хотелось бы увеличить

- размер названия осей
- размер числовых меток на осях
- размер точек на рисунках

Документацию по par(), к сожалению, не поняла, но использовала (после кода выше):

```
    par(cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, cex=1.6,  
    las=1, col=1)
```

И ... не работает!
Все эти аргументы я взяла из функции plot() – там они работают!

P.S. las=1 (поворот чисел на оси ординат) и col=1 (цвет) тоже нужны

Comment: функция `par()` устанавливает параметры графиков. а функция `pairs()` — рисует. сначала установите параметры, а затем рисуйте.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснение, @aleksandr barakin Сработало! А какой нужен аргумент для изменения точек внутри графиков (они не изменились). В документации par () не могу разобраться. Думала, что точки контролируются cex=число, но нет! Просто "cex" ничего не делает, да? нужно что-то добавить через точку?

Comment: Посмотрите `?pairs`, возможно нужный параметр окажется там.

Comment: Действительно, в `pairs()` это делает `font.labels= `. Большое спасибо, @Artem Klevtsov! )